# Facebook debugger not finding meta tags

Tags: seo, php, facebook, laravel

Currently my site (made in Laravel) only displays title and url when shared, even though the og:image and og:description tags are present. I use the laravel SeoTools package, and as far as I can see, all the tags display in the head tag successfully. Facebook debugger tells me the server gives a 418 error, but I have not been able to find any way to address it. When I press the "see what the scraper sees" button, the whole page is blank.

Comment: Could it be an authentication issue?  You have permission but FB does not?  See this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340027/is-418-im-a-teapot-really-an-http-response-code.  See also https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/765686558643258/ and SSL cert issues at the bottom